# represent multiple geometry as single feature

Tags: polygon, features

There is a school. it is on two disjoint areas, one is primary wing and other is secondary. I need to make single feature from the two areas such that, there is only one column in gis table, i.e. only one record.

Also is it possible for them to have separate values but still show up as one record.

Comment: What software are you using?  ArcGIS can do a multipart polygon; that sounds like what you are looking for.  Can read about them here: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t00000036000000.htm

Comment: it should be applicable in any software. ArcGIS, QGIS, Geoserver. It is more about data structure than software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In QGIS you could use the VECTOR > GEOPROCESSING > DISSOLVE tool and dissolve on the "sublocality" field. You will have a multipart polygon and one record for each value in the "sublocality" field.

QGIS dissolve
[image]

In ArcGIS you can use ArcToolbox > Data Management Tools > Generalisation > Dissolve and dissolve on the same field.